# Android Oreo persistent notification "App is running in the background"

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I'm an Android app developer, and is developing an instant message app. The app has a notification problem on Android Oreo system, which shows persistent notification "App is running in the background" and cannot be cleared, and it's OK on system before Android Oreo.

[Screenshot: The phone shows persistent notification App is running in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIjs.png)

I find some discussion, such as [Nexus Help Forum about this question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/IYEQk3zrnEo), but it doesn't work in my phone's settings.

I want to know how to hide this notification programmatically and the app also can receive message instantly because it's an instant message app.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: If you want to receive messages instantly, use push messaging i.e. Firebase.
If you want to run a service permanently, then do it the correct way, with `startForeground()` and a valid notification of your own.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I know, but Firebase is likely to have disconnection problems in China because of GFW, so I have to add a third-party Push library, which led to this problem.

Comment: I hear you @Smiles. Then you are left with doing this the proper way - play nicely with Android and (s)he will play nicely back. Your users want messages, so just make sure the notification reflects something useful for them.

Answer (score 5):

> The app has a notification problem on Android Oreo system, which shows persistent notification "App is running in the background" and cannot be cleared, and it's OK on system before Android Oreo.

You used `startForeground()` with a minimum-importance `Notification`.

> I want to know how to hide this notification programmatically

Use `startForeground()` with a `Notification` that has higher than minimum importance. Or, do not use `startForeground()`.

> I find some install message apps such as WeChat, Facebook doesn't have this problem on Android Oreo

They are not using foreground services, presumably. For example, they might be using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know use startForeground() will cause persistent notification, and I search all my project file but cannot find startForeground() method used. Otherwise, it's OK on system before Android Oreo, so I think this is a problem that related to Android Oreo. My project have been using Google Cloud Messaging(GCM), maybe it's good to update to use FCM.

Comment: @Smiles: "I search all my project file but cannot find startForeground() method used" -- perhaps the notification is coming from a library. Since you have to have a foreground service if you want that service to run for more than a minute, having *some* notification is unavoidable.

Comment: Hum! I also think it might be from a third-party library.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a service which I have called startForeground and added it into a channel with IMPORTANCE_LOW (higher than min). Yet the system "app is running in the background" notification is still showing no matter what I do. This makes me doubt, is there really a correct configuration that would remove the system notification? Based on the official doc (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_MIN), it sounded like the system notification won't show as long as I choose an importance level higher than min (which I did)

Comment: @avelyne: I have not experienced that behavior. If you changed the priority of the channel, try a full uninstall and reinstall of the app, as you cannot change the characteristics of channels once they are created.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the response. I have tried cleaning the whole project and had multiple attempts of fresh install but still the same results. So just to clarify, based on the experience you had, setting IMPORTANCE_LOW to the foreground service channel effectively removed the system "app is running in the background" notification?

Comment: @avelyne: There was always some notification, whether mine or the system's. IIRC, LOW was the threshold for the behavior change.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay thanks for the info. That helped me to confirm that something is really wrong on my end. Despite setting IMPORTANCE_LOW, the system app background notification is ALWAYS there.

IMPORTANCE_MIN: System notif + my notif appear below the shade;

and for IMPORTANCE_LOW: System notif + my notif expanded above the shade. Please let me know if anybody else has experienced the same & has a clue of what might have gone wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @avelyne I've experienced this issue on Android 8.1 with a Foreground service. The notification channel's importance is IMPORTANCE_LOW. This ideally shouldn't be happening as I don't have any work being performed in the background except that I show an overlay using the service. I haven't seen this issue on Android 8.0 (Galaxy S9)

Comment: @avelyne An update to my previous comment. The issue was with Android Studio's 'Instant Run' in my case.  The foreground service notification seem to be removed whenever I used Instant Run and hence the system showed 'app is running in background' notification. This notification won't show up if you have your foreground service notification.

Comment: I couldn't get rid of this notification until I uninstalled production version of the app (which uses different package name and sets `PRIORITY_MIN`). Debug version alone with `PRIORITY_LOW` doesn't cause it. It is probably some bug in 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Before we talk about how to get rid of it, however, let’s talk about why it’s there in the first place.

Basically, in previous versions of Android, there was no real way of knowing if an app was running in the background doing a bunch of stuff it’s not supposed to be doing. In most scenarios, these misbehaving apps would wreak havoc on the battery by keeping the system awake—these are called “wakelocks.” In laymen’s terms, it was keeping the system from sleeping. That’s bad.

With Oreo, Google is calling out developers that let their apps do this sort of thing with the new notification. Essentially, if an app is running in the background and chewing up battery life, this new notification will tell you.

NOTE: There are a few legitimate scenarios where an app will continuously run in the background, like the VPN service running. Often, however, apps are running in the background unjustifiably.

It’s worth noting, though, removing the notification does not solve the issue. Period. There’s a reason this notification exists, and getting rid of it will do nothing to solve the underlying issue. You’ll either need to change a setting within the app or uninstall it altogether.

As long as you understand that and still want to remove it, let’s do this thing.
Because this is a relatively crucial system setting, there’s no way within Oreo itself to remove it. That makes sense.

But like with most things, the developer community has found a way to remove it, and developer iboalali released an app to do just that. It’s actually just called “Hide ‘running in the background’ Notification,” which is about as straightforward as an app name could ever be. Go ahead and give it an install.

Without root, there is no way to actually prevent Android System from displaying the persistent “app is running in the background” notification in Android 8.0 Oreo. Looking at the source code for the ForegroundServiceController, its implementation, and the ForegroundServiceDialog doesn’t really reveal anything we can take advantage of. Programatically nothing have been found so far.

[Here's a Blog post that can help you](https://www.xda-developers.com/hide-app-running-background-notification-android-oreo/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've read the blog post, but I don't want to install other apps to hide the persistent notification. Maybe my install message app has some code that is NOT suitable for Android Oreo? I find some install message apps such as WeChat, Facebook doesn't have this problem on Android Oreo. And I want to make my app more friendly and do not disturb users.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must have the **NotificationListenerService** implementation. Second, in this service (after `onListenerConnected` callback), check the *active ongoing notifications* with packageName called 'android'. And check this notification's **title** is your app name or **text** value is 'App is running in the background' and snooze it.

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

   @Override
   public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {}

   @Override
   public void onListenerConnected() {
      super.onListenerConnected();

      checkOngoingNotification();
   }

   @Override
   public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){

      if(sbn.isOngoing()) { 

         checkOngoingNotification(); 
         return; 
      }
   }

   private void checkOngoingNotification() {

      StatusBarNotification[] activeNotifications = getActiveNotifications();

      Log.i("NLService", "Active notifications size : " + activeNotifications.length);

      for (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : activeNotifications) {

         Log.i("NLService", "notification package  : " + statusBarNotification.getPackageName());
         Log.i("NLService", "notification id       : " + statusBarNotification.getId());
         Log.i("NLService", "notification key      : " + statusBarNotification.getKey());
         Log.i("NLService", "isOngoing             : " + statusBarNotification.isOngoing());
         Log.i("NLService", "isClearable           : " + statusBarNotification.isClearable());
         Log.i("NLService", "groupKey              : " + statusBarNotification.getGroupKey());

         Notification notification = statusBarNotification.getNotification();

         CharSequence title = notification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
         CharSequence text  = notification.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);


         if (title != null && text != null) {

            Log.i("NLService", "title                : " + title);
            Log.i("NLService", "text                 : " + text);


            if (statusBarNotification.getPackageName().equals("android") &&
                (title.toString().contains("Your App Name") || text.toString().contains("App is running"))) {

                long snoozLong = 60000L * 60L * 24L * 20L;

                this.snoozeNotification(statusBarNotification.getKey(), snoozLong);

                Log.i("NLService", "Snoozed notification  : " + title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `startForeground()` with channel's `IMPORTANCE_MIN` is not only one source of the notification. If you call `startForeground()` and give it notification **without** `setSmallIcon()` result will be the same.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ServiceRecord.java#816

Also you could find in logs something like that:

> ActivityManager: Attempted to start a foreground service (ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.ExampleService}) with a broken notification (no icon: Notification(channel=channel_example pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))